# python join strings in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of individual litters,
however I I would like a list of lists of a string.

What I have:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'],
  ['d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
]
```

What I need:

```
[
  ['a b c d e'],
  ['b c d e a'],
  ['c d e a b'],
  ['d e a b c'],
  ['e a b c d']
]
```

Comment: `out = [' '.join(i) for i in lst]`?

Comment: Any reasons why you need a list of singleton lists, rather than a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess below will work as you wish.

```py
list = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'],
  ['d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
]

newList = [[' '.join(elem)] for elem in list]
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension:

```
result = [[' '.join(inner)] for inner in outer_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with this

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']] 

string = [' '.join(i).split(',') for i in array] 
print(string)
```

Comment: Using `split(',')` on a char that is not in the string to create a single element list containing the string is a bit of a hack. Why not `split('‽')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with `map`,

```
list(map(lambda x:[' '.join(x)], lst))
```